# Installing libsqlite3-0 and libsqlite3-dev from sources on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, sqlite3

So I have Ubuntu 18.04 under which the newest version of sqlite3 (and libsqlite3-dev and libsqlite3-0) that can be installed with `apt` is 3.22.0. And I want to install v3.25.0 or higher because it offers new functions that I need, I tried to do that through the sources of v3.25.0, available at: https://distfiles.macports.org/sqlite3/

When I do so, I get the following:

```shell
$ sudo make install-am
make[1]: Entering directory 'XXX/sqlite-autoconf-3250000'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libsqlite3.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so.0 || { rm -f libsqlite3.so.0 && ln -s libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so || { rm -f libsqlite3.so && ln -s libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 libsqlite3.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.lai /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsqlite3.a /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c sqlite3 '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sqlite3.h sqlite3ext.h '/usr/local/include'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sqlite3.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 sqlite3.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
make[1]: Leaving directory 'XXX/sqlite-autoconf-3250000'
```

But when I tried to run an binary that uses the newer version of sqlite3, I get a missing function error:

After looking around for a bit I find out that the version of libsqlite3 that was used by the binary is an old one that was installed by default on ubuntu 18.04 and not the one I though would be installed with the command I ran above.

```shell
$ ls -l  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 april 28 16:04 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1082648 april 28 16:04 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

So my questions are:

- how do I install the newer version of libsqlite3 from the sources?
- I know that it is possible to install libsqlite3-dev and libsqlite3-0 with apt, but as I said above the newest version of them available is 3.22.0 and I need 3.25.0, but since I suppose that apt isntalls the libraries from the sources (which are in the same package as sqlite3), is there a way to get the commands that apt runs to install them?
- Do I need to overwrite the existing installation? And is it safe knowing that many other packages use them?
- If I don't need to overwrite the existing installation, can I just tell my shell to use the version I want so that when I run the command of the binary that uses sqlite3 I don't get the error?